# How to restructure an XML based on 2 conditions?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I have an XML with the following structure:

```
<building>
    <employee>
        <zone>1</zone>
        <system>A</system>
        <name>Jhon</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <zone>1</zone>
        <system>A</system>
        <name>Paul</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <zone>1</zone>
        <system>B</system>
        <name>Matt</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <zone>2</zone>
        <system>A</system>
        <name>Bob</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <zone>2</zone>
        <system>A</system>
        <name>Peter</name>
    </employee>
</building>
```

The Employees are sorted by zone and system ascending.

How I can restructure the XML with the following format?:

```
<building>
    <block>
        <employee>
            <zone>1</zone>
            <system>A</system>
            <name>Jhon</name>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <zone>1</zone>
            <system>A</system>
            <name>Paul</name>
        </employee>
    </block>
    <block>
        <employee>
            <zone>1</zone>
            <system>B</system>
            <name>Matt</name>
        </employee>
    </block>
    <block>
        <employee>
            <zone>2</zone>
            <system>A</system>
            <name>Bob</name>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <zone>2</zone>
            <system>A</system>
            <name>Peter</name>
        </employee>
    </block>
</building>
```

The grouping conditions are by zone and system (For those employees who share the same zone and the same system).

I tried with XSLT and XQuery without any success.

Comment: Well, you talk about "grouping conditions", so how about trying an example from https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#grouping-examples and adapting that or an example from the XQuery spec?

Comment: The relevant link from the XQuery spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-group-by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to group on "2 conditions", you can combine those conditions to create a composite key.

It's a good idea to use a separator so you get accurate keys. The combining can be done with `concat()` (XPath 1.0 or 2.0) or `string-join()` (XPath 2.0 only).

Here are a few examples. You'll notice that in all 3 I basically use the same thing to create the grouping key: `concat(zone,'|',system)`

**XSLT 1.0 (or 2.0)** (Muenchian grouping)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="employeeByBlock" match="employee" use="concat(zone,'|',system)"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="employee[count(.|key('employeeByBlock',concat(zone,'|',system))[1])=1]">
        <xsl:sort select="zone"/>
        <xsl:sort select="system" data-type="text"/>
        <block>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('employeeByBlock',concat(zone,'|',system))">
            <xsl:sort select="name" data-type="text"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </block>
      </xsl:for-each>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 2.0** (`xsl:for-each-group`)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="employee" group-by="concat(zone,'|',system)">
        <xsl:sort select="zone"/>
        <xsl:sort select="system" data-type="text"/>        
        <block>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
            <xsl:sort select="name" data-type="text"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </block>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XQuery 3.0** (`group by`)

```
xquery version "3.0";
<building>{
for $employee in /building/employee
let $zone := $employee/zone
let $system := $employee/system
group by $zone, $system 
order by $zone, $system
return
    <block>{
    for $x in $employee
    order by $x/name
    return $x
    }</block>
}</building>
```

All three of these examples produce the same output*:

```
<building>
   <block>
      <employee>
         <zone>1</zone>
         <system>A</system>
         <name>Jhon</name>
      </employee>
      <employee>
         <zone>1</zone>
         <system>A</system>
         <name>Paul</name>
      </employee>
   </block>
   <block>
      <employee>
         <zone>1</zone>
         <system>B</system>
         <name>Matt</name>
      </employee>
   </block>
   <block>
      <employee>
         <zone>2</zone>
         <system>A</system>
         <name>Bob</name>
      </employee>
      <employee>
         <zone>2</zone>
         <system>A</system>
         <name>Peter</name>
      </employee>
   </block>
</building>
```

*Tested XSLT 1.0 with Saxon 6.5.5. Tested XSLT 2.0 and XQuery with Saxon-HE 9.5.

Comment: Is there a need in XQuery 3.0 to use string concatenation to build a key from two items? https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-group-by suggests you can group by several key values directly e.g. `group by $zone := $employee/zone, $system := $employee/system`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Good catch. I had just copied/pasted. I'm sure you're correct. I will test real quick and then update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielHaley thank you very much!, the XSLT 1.0 version works fine for me :D big hugs!!!